# How do I update system.net.http HttpRequestMessageExtensions

Tags: .net, updates

I am looking at two different applications both have references to the system.net version 4.0 when I look at the projects, yet in the Solution on the left I have an newer version and would like to use something from that version in the Solution on the right.

How can I update this ?
[SolutionsDifference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3vT0.png)

Comment: As you can see, those are entirely different assemblies, coincidentally containing a similarly named class in the same namespace. If you want the left file in the right project, add the relevant NuGet package.

Comment: Massive Coincidence, How can I decipher which assembly I need, to find to the correct one ?

Comment: The package and assembly name are shown in the comment on top of the file.